# Keycloak SSO with Angular & Spring Boot - How to use Spring Boot to fetch token after redirect?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, keycloak

I have a setup of Angular & Spring Boot configured with Keycloak. We have an issue where the manager concerned with setting up of Keycloak has not given a CORS entry into WebOrigins of the configuration, and doesn't want to allow invocation of `/token` endpoint from the browser to fetch the access token, saying it's insecure to do so. That's causing a CORS error.

Is there any way, where I could instead use the Spring Boot application to fetch the token after the redirect back to application post successful login has been completed, or any alternative where I can circumvent this scenario?

Update:

I see an OPTIONS request going to the /token endpoint, probably as a pre-flight request, which is 200OK. But the subsequent POST request that goes, is facing the CORS: No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header error.

Comment: The Keycloak client that you are using, in the WebOrigins what do you have there?

Comment: @dreamcrash I suppose there isn't anything there. That's what I understood, could not have a chance to look at the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using keycloak open-id [api](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#endpoints)

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
String keycloakUrl = MessageFormat.format("{0}/realms/{1}/protocol/openid-connect/token", keycloakAuthServiceUrl, keycloakRealm);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(keycloakUrl);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", <clientId>));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", <userId>));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", <password>));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
String str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).